# divs side by side in container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create two divs side by side. I tried to put `float: left` in `.holder-left` and `float: right` in `.holder-right` but they are floating outside the parent holder and content divs.

How can I solve it?

**CSS**

```
div.holder {
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    width: 1002px;
}

div.holder > div.holder-left {
    float: left;
}

div.holder > div.holder-right {
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="holder-left">
        aufgftf ftftfy
    </div>
    <div class="holder-right">
        afytf fttyfttyty
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution is modify `div.holder` by adding the `overfow` property. This will allow the outer div to properly wrap the inner, floated divs. I don't remember why, but there is some quirky-ness with this solution, so see the "clearfix" solution below.

```
div.holder {
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    width: 1002px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

Although, you should properly implement the "clearfix" solution. (Here you don't need to use the `overflow` property as shown above.) Here is the CSS for the clearfix solution I use:

```
.group:after{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

* html .group{ zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .group { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Then change your HTML for the floated divs as shown below. All you need to do is add the `group` class to the div that contains the floated elements. This will ensure the floated divs stay completely inside the outer one.

```
<div class="holder group">
    <div class="holder-left">aufgftf ftftfy</div>
    <div class="holder-right">afytf fttyfttyty</div>
</div>
```

[Here is the source for this clearfix solution.](http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/)

Comment: If I ever find the source for this solution again, I'll post it.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler I was further researching about the clearfix and found this: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html. Maybe it's the original code and if not, it is very well explained, proved and documented. Thank you for let me know.

Comment: I think I found the source I used, and linked to it in my answer.